# Combining 1600mhz and 1333mhz Ram

Tags: memory

Actually we have an ESX Server running with 32gb Ram ( 2 pairs of 8gb ), and in need of more memory we purchased more 64gb ram ( 2 pairs of 1600hmz 32gb).

My question is, since this server is exclusive for serving VM's, could i mix 1300mhz and 1600mhz ?

the server we are using is an [Asus RS700-x7 ps4](http://www.asus.com/en/Commercial_Servers_Workstations/RS700X7PS4/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related SU question: [Can I merge 4gb of ram at 1333mhz with 4gb of ram at 1600mhz](http://superuser.com/questions/714992/can-i-merge-4gb-of-ram-at-1333mhz-with-4gb-of-ram-at-1600mhz?rq=1)

Comment: -1  downvoted because you should have realized your question is so common it is obviously going to be very googlable. People have been asking these questions overy and over again re mixing their DDR RAM for over a decade always the same answer.

Comment: I did the research, but i think it's better be safe than sorry, plus i like to make my own questions :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can mix 1333 and 1600 MHz RAM sticks, however the system will downclock all RAM to the speed of the slowest stick.

For best performance, try and buy RAM that is the same speed or faster.

Answer (score 2):

If the server does accept it, all modules will run at the highest possible speed common to them - in this case 1300mhz. If you have already bought more modules, there's nothing to do except 1) read the manual for the motherboard or 2) try it. I doubt very much trying the new modules will do any harm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks, but it is clear as rain: If the server does accept it, all modules will run at the highest possible speed common to them - in this case 1300mhz. If the OP has already bought more modules, theres nothing to do except 1) read the manual for the motherboard or 2) try it. I doubt very much trying the new modules will do any harm.

Comment: This comment would have been a much better answer